# Check response time of a website with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I want to check response times of website. Here is my code, I got some values but doesn't show reality. What is the problem with these codes. Is it sth related with cache?? Furthermore how to show if page doesn't exit or unavailable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
 var start = new Date();
 $.ajax ({
 url: 'http://www.example.com',
 complete : function()
 {
  alert(new Date() - start)
 },
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: *"Furthermore how to show if page doesn't exit or unavailable."* Ask *one* question per question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code itself is fine assuming that the code is running on the same origin as the one it's checking; you [can't use ajax cross-origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless both ends (client and server) support and are using [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

It could be caching, yes, you'd have to refer to the browser tools (any decent browser has a Network tab or similar in its developer tools) to know for sure. You can also disable caching by setting `cache: false` in the `ajax` call (see the [`ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details), although that's a somewhat synthetic way to do it. A better way would be to ensure that whatever URL you're using for this timing responds with cache headers telling the browser (and proxies) not to cache it.

You can tell if the page doesn't exist or is "unavailable" (whatever that means) by hooking the `error` function and looking at the information it gives you:

```
var start = new Date();
$.ajax ({
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    error : function(jqxhr, status, ex) {
        // Look at status here
    },
    complete : function()
    {
        alert(new Date() - start)
    },
});
```

The arguments given to `error` are also described in the docs linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. The only problem is even if page doesn't exist, I get a response time. How to show if page doesn't exist. thanks...

Comment: @user1874941: Glad that helped. *"The only problem is even if page doesn't exist, I get a response time."* Again, if you refer to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you'll see that `complete` is called when the request completes, regardless of whether that completion was success or failure. If you only want to look at successful outcomes, use `success` instead. If the page doesn't exist, you'll get an `error` callback but no `success` callback (`complete` occurs either way).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this due to the same origin policy.

One trick would be to create an image and measure the time until the onerror event fires.

```
var start = new Date();

var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function() {
    alert(new Date() - start);
};

img.src = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

Append a random number to the url to prevent caching.

Comment: note the `complete` function does get called (even if as an error code)

Comment: It seems like it doesn't follow redirects, whereas the image does. I compared the times to `curl` vs `curl -L`, and it corresponds to the AJAX method vs the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use browser extensions such as Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to measure Ajax response times.